How to Authenticate Jira via c# SDK
I am using this SDK https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/ to interact with Jira.
var client = Atlassian.Jira.Jira.CreateRestClient(new JiraRestClient("https://xxxxx.atlassian.net", "xxxx%40gmail.com", "xxxx"));
// use LINQ syntax to retrieve issuesjira.CreateIssue("My Project");
var issue = client.CreateIssue("TestProject");
issue.Type = "Bug";
issue.Priority = "Major";
issue.Summary = "Alert Testing";

var result =  await issue.SaveChangesAsync();
Unfortunately when I run this code, it says  You are not authenticated. Authentication required to perform this operation. I triple checked, I can access that url and authenticate via the email and password. But it seems to not work via the SDK. May I ask if anyone have any tips or suggestions? I tried encoding the username and password as well but that didn't help. Is the userid something other than the email I use?

It would help if you used a Jira token instead of a password.
Here, you can find a guide on how to create it.
var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("https://*organization*.atlassian.net", *your email*, *created Jira token*);

